# How to add Remote JVM Debug to Jboss Remote Java configuration in intellij like in Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I have recently changed from eclipse to intellij and I am missing the following feature:
On eclipse I have configured remote java debugger and **added it to Jboss Remote Java Configurations which I am missing on intellij** like you can see in the following screenshot:
[image]

On intellij, I have also configured remote JVM Debug like you can see in the following screenshot. **How can I add the created remote JVM Debug configuration to Jboss debugger analog to eclipse?** Without this step I can debug bug the changes on java code do not reflect before I created built the project and restarted wildfly.
[image]